# How to get the link of table from where data is coming onto html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

For example there is a table like in this link https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-309/ranking
How to access the database from where it is coming. Like let's say to get whole ranking table at a place

I tried reading HTML file but didn't get it
One extension scrapes the table only
How can we achieve this?

Comment: It looks like the web page is making an API call to the following url: https://leetcode.com/contest/api/ranking/weekly-contest-309/?pagination=1&region=global

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer here - it really depends how is it implemented on the server side. As **rv.kvetch** pointed you can get part of result from url:
https://leetcode.com/contest/api/ranking/weekly-contest-309/?pagination=1&region=global

You can notice `pagination` query parameter here, indeed you can access [second page](https://leetcode.com/contest/api/ranking/weekly-contest-309/?pagination=2&region=global), [third page](https://leetcode.com/contest/api/ranking/weekly-contest-309/?pagination=3&region=global) and so on. Sometimes there is some parameter like `page_size` implemented on server but it doesn't look like that case.

So to access full table you probably need to iterate over that pages and glue the results.

EDIT: How to get such url for some page?

Open your favorive browser, run `web inspector` (usually right click - inspect) and go to `network` tab, where you can find all requests sent during page rendering.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Information... Could you please let me know from where was this found?

Comment: What "this" is?

Comment: this refers to link....

Comment: Updadet the answer, hope it helps!